# Delphi XE8 Firemonkey PrinterSetupDialog two pages on one A4

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

I need to print two pages on one A4 sheet. I am using the PrinterSetupDialog component to set printer options. Then i print two pages using this code below, but both are on separate A4 sheets.

What am I doing wrong?

Im using Delphi XE8 and this is Firemonkey application.

Regards.

Simple print procedure:

```
var
  SrcRect, DestRect: TRectF;
  vBitmap: TBitmap;
begin
  if PrinterSetupDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    Printer.ActivePrinter.SelectDPI(1200, 1200);

    { Set canvas filling style. }
    Printer.Canvas.Fill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.White;
    Printer.Canvas.Fill.Kind := TBrushKind.Solid;

    { Start printing. }
    Printer.BeginDoc;

    { Set the Destination TRects. }
    DestRect := TRectF.Create(0, 0, Printer.PageWidth, Printer.PageHeight);

    vBitmap := TBitmap.Create;
    try
      { Page 1 }
      vBitmap.LoadFromFile('D:\Page1.bmp');
      SrcRect.Width := vBitmap.Width;
      SrcRect.Height := vBitmap.Height;
      { Print the picture on all the surface of the page and all opaque. }
      Printer.Canvas.DrawBitmap(vBitmap, SrcRect, DestRect, 1);


      { Page 2 }
      vBitmap.LoadFromFile('D:\Page2.bmp');
      SrcRect.Width := vBitmap.Width;
      SrcRect.Height := vBitmap.Height;
      { Add new Page}
      Printer.NewPage;
      { Print the picture on all the surface of the page and all opaque. }
      Printer.Canvas.DrawBitmap(vBitmap, SrcRect, DestRect, 1);
    finally
      vBitmap.Free;
    end;

    { Finish printing job. }
    Printer.EndDoc;
  end;
end;
```

## 1 Update

Removing `SelectDPI` line give me no results.

But i made this code on VCL and it work.

```
var
  SrcRect, DestRect: TRect;
  vBitmap: TBitmap;
begin
  if PrinterSetupDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    Printer.BeginDoc;

    DestRect := Rect(0, 0, Printer.PageWidth, Printer.PageHeight);

    vBitmap := TBitmap.Create;
    try
      vBitmap.LoadFromFile('D:\Page1.bmp');
      SrcRect := Rect(0, 0, vBitmap.Width, vBitmap.Height);
      Printer.Canvas.CopyRect(DestRect, vBitmap.Canvas, SrcRect);

      Printer.NewPage;

      vBitmap.LoadFromFile('D:\Page2.bmp');
      SrcRect := Rect(0, 0, vBitmap.Width, vBitmap.Height);
      Printer.Canvas.CopyRect(DestRect, vBitmap.Canvas, SrcRect);
    finally
      vBitmap.Free;
    end;

    Printer.EndDoc;
  end;
end;
```

## 2 Update

I solved this problem with writing a print module in VCL, but i will describe my observations.

I think it is a bug on my version of Delphi, Settings from `FMX.Printer.TPrintDialog`
and `FMX.Printer.TPrinterSettupDialog` are ignored while printing. But this components
in VCL version works ok, for Windows.
I tested on MAC and it works only on `FMX.Printer.TPrintDialog`, `TPrinterSettupDialog`
not showing up.

Regards.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, take [**The Tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) for a brief intro on Stack Overflow, and then read [**Asking**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to learn what you can ask about and how to present your question. Pay attention to [**Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You must provide the means to reproduce the problem you are having.

Comment: Specifically regarding your question, be precise. What options are you setting with the `Fmx.Printer.TprintSetupDialog`, that are ignored?

Comment: No matter what i set in "PrinterSetupDialog.Execute", the printout has default settings.
For example, in "PrinterSetupDialog1.Execute" i set two pages on one A4 then close settings window when i reopen settings again everything is set as before, but print has default settings.
Should I assign settings from PrinterSetupDialog same how to FMX.Printer.TPrinter?
Or i must to implement this options myself?
thanks for help and sory for my english ( ͡° ʖ̯ ͡°)

Comment: Well, whatever I set in the dialog, it just works and remains until I shut down the app. You must be doing something differently. If I set 4 pages per sheet, the printer prints 4 pages per sheet of paper. If I set 2 pages per sheet, the printer prints 2 pages per sheet. You really need to edit your question, strip down your code to the minimum to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Ok, im gona make same test app without not necessary code. thanks.

Comment: In test application is the same problem. I was edited my question.

Comment: Much better, I would normally hope for the bitmaps too, at least their sizes, and info on wether the size matters. Anyway, I made some tests with some bitmaps I had around.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the problem is the line

```
Printer.ActivePrinter.SelectDPI(1200, 1200);
```

This resets the `Pages per sheet` setting to 1 (probably/possibly other properties too). Removing the line cures the problem.
The DPI setting is available in all printer setup dialogs I have on my system, maybe you can leave it to the users responsibility while they are setting up other properties. Anyway I would not make such a setting hardcoded.

Comment: I removed this line but unfortunately settings from dialog are still ignored. They are saved on application sesion, but ignored on print. I tried even run app with admin rights without any results.
Does this code work well for you(without dpi line ofc)?

Comment: @Ancool I tested yesterday in FMX, using Delphi XE7. Now, that I test with XE8, there is something "fishy", but I'm not so sure it only depends on the Delphi version. I continue investigating. I'll be back!

Comment: Maybe it is a bug, i had a lot of this in XE8 FMX controls. For now i need to write VCL module for print. But app will for other platforms to.
And thanks for your time.

Comment: @Ancool I'm leaning to agree with you, and will still see if I can find the culprit. Which other platforms are you targeting at the end?

Comment: It is almost finalized under Win, MAC and in the future it maybe under android.